# both through the create-react-app to make build for development?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

both through the create-react-app to make build for development?

I need to be on the server shows errors react

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": react-scripts start",
    "build":  react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",

  },
```

Comment: Some opening quotes are missing. Look closely at your code block -- `react-scripts start` and `react-scripts build` are highlighted in a different color than the rest of the code. That's a clue.

Answer (score 1):

I'm bamboozled by your question, but do you just need to add quotes around the commands?

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build":  "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
```

Comment: NB: JSON usually doesn't like trailing commas (the comma after the eject command)

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake), I do not copy the code properly. But another question

Comment: @Starbax What does "I need to be on the server shows errors react" mean? Can you try to type that message out at greater length? If English is not your first language, maybe you could use Google Translate or post in your original language as well so we can understand you?

Comment: @Starbax did this answer your question?